# Slice String using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to slice the input text Field Value using Angular JS

**HTML FORM**

```
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="cardExp">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
console.log($scope.cardExp) //output : 122016
```

I want to  make text field value ("122016") into variables a and b and their vales are

1. a is first  two digits
2. b is next 4 digits

Thanks,

Comment: AngularJS is JavaScript, so you would do it the same in AngularJS as you would in JavaScript. You'll want to look into [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: Do you want to do this during binding (automagically)?  Or somewhere in a controller?

Comment: Yes, the value Is user input

Comment: If this is regarding the expiration date of something, from a UX point of view, I would suggest separating year and month into two different inputs.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: @AlbertoRivera, Yes True, But that is the requirement

Comment: @MohammadFareed check the sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use plain javascript.

```
var a = $scope.cardExp.substring(0, 2);
var b = $scope.cardExp.substring(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var app = angular.module('store', []);
  app.controller('StoreController', function($scope) {
    $scope.str = '122016';
    $scope.splited = $scope.str.match(/.{1,4}/g);
    $scope.a = $scope.splited[0];
    $scope.b = $scope.splited[1];
  });
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/thK5QoZfLhBcWEjw4cwc?p=preview)**